# how to create a button in 2010 and 2007 excel that in one click the selected data will be transfered in a specific sheet?

Tags: performance, excel

I need your help. I am creating a database and I need to create a button that will help me transfer selected cells/data to a separate sheet. I have "pended" cases that I need to copy and paste on a sheet named "Pending Cases" and I'd like to do it by inserting a button on a sheet. I know this is possible. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: How are you selecting the cells to be copied? Manually or is it always a specific range?

Answer (score 0):

To add a button you can display the Develop Tab. In Excel 2010 right-click in the Ribbon, choose Customize the Ribbon, and click Developer on the right-hand side. In 2007, click the Office Button, Options, and this option is towards the top of the first Tab.

In the Develop Tab, Controls Group, click Insert and choose Form Controls, Button. When you drag to draw this on the worksheet it will then ask you to assign a macro to this button. You can Record a macro from here, or type a name for your procedure and press New.

The following code copies data from one sheet range to another.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B4").Value = _
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```